# Angular - ViewContainerRef availability timing?

Tags: javascript, angular

Looking at a rough implementation of `ngIf` :

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myNgIf]'})
export class MyNgIfDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set myNgIf(condition: boolean) {
    if (condition) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Getter and setter of input are set initially and raise the `ngOnchanges` event. This is the first event even before `ngInit`.

But In that setter we are actually using the `viewContainer` (`which is type of <ViewContainerRef>`) - but how come it has access to it at the stage ?

**Question**

I was expecting to see this line :

```
 this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)  ,
```

— at a *later-Already-available-view-stage* such as `ngAfterViewInit` - so how come it still works and have access to view container?

I already know about `*` which desugar it to a template syntax but still I don't understand how view-container is already available at that stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably know that every element can be used as a view container. So a directive applied to any element can inject the view container associated with the element it's applied on into constructor:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[adir]'
})
export class ADirective {
  constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef) {
    console.log(this.vc.element.nativeElement.nodeName); // `DIV`
  }
```

And I can apply the directive to any element:

```
<div adir></div>
```

And this is essentially how `ngIf` gets access to the view container.

What's even more interesting is that Angular processes @ViewChild queries [before the digest starts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L312) and so the static `@ViewChild` elements are available in `ngOnInit`. It means that you can do like this:

```
@ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc;

ngOnInit() {
   this.vc; // already available
}
```

Comment: But the element itself (div) is not available until viewinit.... No? So I'm surprised that your test work

Comment: well... it's a long answer. in short, it doesn't matter when the DOM element is created because angular uses different representation of html elements. It creates view nodes with all the relevant information. You can start with these two articles: [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d) and [Here is why you will not find components inside Angular](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c)

Comment: still, DOM elements are created when Angular instantiates views long before the [change detection cycle](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) starts and lifecycle hooks are called as part of change detection

Comment: I can swear that I've read that viewchild is available only after viewinit

Comment: yeah, that's the safest place because `@ViewChild` can go several component views deep and in that case some view children will not be available before `ngAfterViewInit`, but for static html view childs are processed [when angular creates view nodes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L312) before the change detection which is usually used to [update queries](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7edc5e96f373d7c74092b92874fa6c69b308d8dc/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L348)